# How to Join external customer table and internal customer table base on name

Tags: mysql, join

I have two customer table, internal and external both with name， email address
I have another shopping list table which join these customer table by name.

how I can get the shopping list given name in one sql?

```
shopping item |  customer name|  customer email|
```

is there a way to join one table if not found then join another table?

DDL is like

```
CREATE TABLE `shoppinglist` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customername` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `itemname` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE `internalcustomer` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE `externalcustomer` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
)
```

Currently I have to use two sql

```
select list.itemname, intcustomer.name, intcustomer.email from shoppinglist list
join internalcustomer intcustomer on intcustomer.name = list.customname;

select list.itemname, extcutomer.name, extcutomer.email from shoppinglist list
join externalcustomer extcutomer on extcutomer.name = list.customname;
```

ps: the name should be uniq across both table

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output, thank you. Please provide DDL command as well

Comment: Did you try out UNION?

Comment: Kindly share query that you tried so far, so we can have a better understanding on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You may use UNION

```
select list.itemname, intcustomer.name, intcustomer.email from shoppinglist list
join internalcustomer intcustomer on intcustomer.name = list.customname
UNION
select list.itemname, extcutomer.name, extcutomer.email from shoppinglist list
join externalcustomer extcutomer on extcutomer.name = list.customname;
```

Please use UNION ALL if you want to allow duplicate values. Else, UNION operator selectes only distinct values